# Laravel 5: `select()` and `all()` methods do not work, `where` method does. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel framework and have been watching the Laracasts and reading the docs to learn the system. So far so good, but now I'm going down the road of accessing a second database and I'm running into problems. For some reason I can pull data from the database by using the `where()` method, but it breaks (page doesn't load, no errors shown, log file empty) when I use either the `select()` or `all()` methods and I can't figure out why.

Here is my Model:

```
class SharedAircraft extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
]; // This is done to block any possible entries for now. Find a better solution before production.

protected $connection = 'pams_shared'; // Point to the shared database

protected $table = 'shared_aircraft'; // This overrides the Laravel default to look for the plural version of the class.
```

}

Here is my Controller that breaks, same result if I use `all()`:

```
public function create()
{
    $aircraft = SharedAircraft::select('aircraft_mfr','aircraft_model')->get();
    return view('aircraft.create', compact('aircraft'));
}
```

Here is my Controller that works:

```
public function create()
{
    $aircraft = SharedAircraft::where('aircraft_mfr','Cessna')->get();
    return view('aircraft.create', compact('aircraft'));
}
```

Here is my aircraft.create view:

```
<select>
    @foreach($aircraft as $id)
        <option value="{{ $id->shared_aircraft_id }}">{{ $id->aircraft_mfr.' '.$id->aircraft_model }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is the second connection in my database.php:

```
    'pams_shared' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'pams_shared'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'pams_admin'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '************'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I do have the Model loaded within the Controller:

```
use App\SharedAircraft;
```

I was thinking there might be a way to force an error message, but I hit a wall there as well.

Appreciate your help.

**UPDATE 1**

There are three other tables within the `pams_shared` database, they are: `shared_engines`, `shared_ata_codes` and `shared_propellers`. When I try `DB::table('pams_shared.shared_aircraft')->get();` it breaks and displays only a white page, BUT when I try any of the others, it works! So, `DB::table('pams_shared.shared_engines')->get();` works as expected! would this mean there is something wrong with that one table?

**UPDATE 2**

I have confirmed that the table `shared_aircraft` is causing the problem. I renamed the table to `shared_broken` and created a new table called `shared_aircraft`, inserted some data and everything works as expected.
Now the question is, what would cause this? Bad data? I've checked my field types and they all match the data. What else would cause this scenario??

Comment: What do you get from dd($aircraft) in your 'broken' controller?

Comment: Have you tried `$aircraft = SharedAircraft::all()->select('aircraft_mfr','aircraft_model')->get();`

Comment: Go to `storage/logs` and review the errors there. You can post the error that you got, so we can help you.

Comment: You tried this? ->  return view('aircraft.create')->with('aircraft' => $aircraft);

Comment: @aethergy if I add: dd($aircraft); I don't get anything at all, as though it wasn't even there.

Comment: @GeorgeQ I copied your code in place of mine and got the same result.

Comment: @shaddy I did check my logs (I did mention that in my post) and there are no errors being recorded.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca I copied your code into place and received this error:

FatalErrorException in AircraftController.php line 45: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: @JoeneFloresca I looked up the correct syntax and tried ->with('aircraft', $aircraft); as well, no luck.

Comment: @AndrewFox sounds like your problem might be occurring before the create method is called. I think it would help if you posted more of your code. Are your two create method examples from two separate controllers?

Comment: First, check `storage/` permissions, set it as 777 for now. If this is an error it has to be in the logs. Second, if `dd(SharedAircraft::all());` returns a white page, it's an error and permissions will probably fix it. If it dumps `[]` then we have a problem. Won't be the problem but I'd create the view as: `return view('aircraft.create')->withAircrafts( SharedAircraft::all() );`, in your view the variable would be $aircrafts.

Comment: @hfingler logs are being created, there just none related to this. Today I had two errors total, one was from a syntax error and the other was from when I changed database settings in an effort to resolve the issue. I can confirm that dd(SharedAircraft::all()); returns a white page.

Comment: @aethergy the Controller is the same one, called AircraftController. I wondered the same thing, if it was failing before the create() method was called, but if I change it to Aircraft::all(); it works fine. Aircraft is pointed to the default database, called pams_free, and SharedAircraft points to the second database called pams_shared.

Comment: I can't get my head around how it would work fine, meaning it connects to the database and calls the method properly, when I specify a where condition but breaks when I try to select. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndrewFox have you tried using a raw query to see what happens?

Comment: @aethergy I tried DB::table(pams_shared.shared_aircraft)->get(); but got the same result. VERY interesting find though, when I changed tables within the same shared database, it worked!! Update my question with details.

Comment: Ah. Does sound like an issue with the table then.

Comment: @AndrewFox could be isolated to a single row with improperly formatted data or something. Can you test each row individually to maybe pinpoint? Have you tried running `CHECK TABLE`?

Comment: @aethergy yes, I ran Check Table and Defragment Table as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here looking for an answer, my problem turned out to be bad data in the table. I figured it out by replacing my existing `shared_aircraft` and inserting a few lines. It worked. Thanks for the help!